# JQM 1.1 - data-rel=back only in the same domain?

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile (at least 1.1) provides a nice feature that is a "go back" button. According to the chapter "Back button link" [in the docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html), adding `data-rel="back"` on a link/button will simulate the exact same feature as the web browser back button. That is, going back to the previous page in the user web browser.

This feature is great (and works), but **there's an use case where you don't get the right behaviour for a mobile app**.

So you have a website. It's jquery mobile.

- Page A is the landing page
- Page B is a child page of page A
- Page C is a child page of page B **but also a child page from page A**
- Now Bob gives the URL of page C to Alice
- Alice goes to page C and uses the back button because she wants to checkout the rest of the site
- Alice's web browser goes back to the previous page she was on (it could be stackoverflow!)
- Alice doesn't understand why she is redirected to another website, and in that misery of her, she throws her phone in the lake.

Since there are two ways to go to page C, the developer has put a back button because in a nominal use case, every user enters from page A and browses and the back button on page C works as wanted ; that is, it either goes back to page A or to page B. But with Alice and Bob here, the back button goes to a completly different website !

I hope all this is clear :)

So what I see as a solution is :

- If the previous website in the user's history stack is on the same domain : use this to go back
- If not : use the `href` attribute value as the navigation rule.

So ... the question : is this supported in jqm ? Did I miss something in the docs ? Is it implemented in some way ? Do I need to implement it myself ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is entirely possible. JQuerymobile lets you find out the previous page like below:

```
$("#C").on("pageshow",function(){
  if ( "undefined" == typeof $(ui.prevPage)[0] ){
     //disable-back button here
     //$("#C").removeAttr('data-rel');
     // $(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );
  } 
});
```

However, browser history is managed by browser and by the time you reach this page, history is already set. If you are using a framework like phonegap, you may be able to disable the backbutton by calling `navigator.app.overrideBackbutton(true)`, but then how will the user ever go back? Alternatively, you may be able to give a warning to user asking them to confirm that they are leaving your page.